# Unable to parse time string

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I need to format `"Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am"` from my DB into an iso string but I keep getting an invalid date object when trying.

i tried this.
 `moment(value.note.noteTime).format("dddd, MMMM Do, h:mm a")`
and it returns `"Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am"`and gets stored in my DB.

el.time is in the same format as `"Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am"`

also tried this.

`console.log(moment(el.Time,moment.ISO_8601))` 
or 
`console.log(moment(el.Time).format())`

How would I parse el.time into an iso string?

Comment: What's `el` ? is this the String representation of the time ?

Comment: el.time is in the same format as "Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am" It's just within a forEach loop

Comment: So `el.Time` is a String ?

Comment: yes ```el.Time="Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am"``` how do i get this into an iso format?

Comment: Why would you store a display version of a date on a database instead of storing it as an actual date?

Comment: @JuanMendes so I only have to change it to an iso string once instead of changing it from an iso string anytime i want to display it.

Comment: @SockMonkey Best practice is to store it is a date so you can display it in any format you need, even another language. If they decide to show 24 hr format, you can make that change. With your decision, you'd have to make a lot of db updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Specifying the format of date while using moment and
2. With toISOString() would avoid that Invalid Date error

Issue: Date provided to moment must be known format to avoid Invalid date error, Specifying formats would always best option to avoid parsing by moment.
Please refer this link for moment accepted formats- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

```js
var t = "Wednesday, May 15th, 11:36 am"
console.log(moment(t, "dddd, MMMM Do, h:mm a").toISOString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gJmpge

Comment: It's always better to explain what the problem was along with the solution. The problem is that the OP was specifying the incorrect formatting (`moment.ISO_8601` instead of `"dddd, MMMM Do, h:mm a"` )when asking `moment` to parse it?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes, I agree with you and updated my answer